# passing data between android activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to pass data between two activities in my android application however when 
i try the run the on click method that sends the data the app crashes.

This is the code of the activity that works out my calculation is trying to send it to another activity called result. The variable output I am trying to send is a double.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(BMIMetric.this, result.class);
BMIMetric.this.startActivity(myIntent);
myIntent.putExtra("key", output);
```

Then on the results page I am trying to take the variable with this code

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
double output = (Double) getIntent().getExtras().get("Key");
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know from the CatLog what the exact error is, but for what it's worth, you do have "Key" capitalized when fetching it and lowercase when setting it. Don't remember if this will affect things offhand or not, but it's a place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have an order issue (edited code):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(BMIMetric.this, result.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", output);
BMIMetric.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

You need to set extras before starting the new Activity.

Then in your other Activity do:

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
double output = getDoubleExtra ("key", -1.0);
```

`getDoubleExtra()` seems like a better fit since you're assigning to a primitive data type.

Also, as Blumer mentioned, `"key"` had a different spelling. You need the same spelled key, that's how it works. Otherwise you're mentioning something different and it won't be found.

And as an addition to using `getExtras()` - if you use `getExtras().get()` and the key is not found, you will get `null` in return. Although `Double`s can auto-box/unbox nowadays, if you do

```
Double doubleObject = null;
double d = doubleObject;
```

You will still get a `NullPointerException`.